# How to send a body with HTTP DELETE when using WebFlux?

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-webflux

I want to access an HTTP API which provides a `DELETE` endpoint. This particular endpoint expects a list of items (which I want to delete) as JSON body.

Now, my problem is, I'm using Spring Webflux. But its [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html) doesn't give me the possibility, to send a body with a `DELETE` request. For a `POST`, I'd do this:

```
webClient.post()
         .uri("/foo/bar")
         .body(...)
         .exchange()
```

But for `DELETE`, I get a [RequestHeadersSpec](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec.html) which doesn't give me the option to provide a `body(...)`:

```
webClient.delete()
         .uri("/foo/bar")
         .body(...)       <--- METHOD DOES NOT EXIST
         .exchange()
```

So, what's the way to achieve this with Spring Webflux on the client side?

Comment: According to [RFC 7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) `A payload within a DELETE request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a DELETE request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request.`. You are dealing therefore with some non-standard-conform extension that might not be supported by default

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use webClient's `method()` operator. Simple example,

```
return webClient
        .method(HttpMethod.DELETE)
        .uri("/delete")
        .body(BodyInserters.fromProducer(Mono.just(new JSONObject().put("body","stringBody").toString()), String.class))
        .exchange()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
  return webClient
            .method(HttpMethod.DELETE)
            .uri(url)
            .body(Mono.just(request), requestClass)
            .retrieve() 
            .toEntity(Void.class);
```

As result, we will get:

```
 Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>>
```